# error when using mongorestore to replay oplog with binData field

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore, bindata

When using mongorestore with option --oplogReplay to replay oplogs, I found a strange error that mongorestore cannot handle binData field's set operation. You maybe meet the same error if you do this:

1. insert a test data.

   ```
   db.testData.insert({_id: 10000, data: BinData(0, ""), size: 10})
   ```
2. update its binData field.

   ```
   db.testData.update({_id: 10000}, {$set: {data: BinData(0, "CgxVfs93PiT/DrxMSvASFgoNMTAuMTYwLjIyMi4xMhDEJxgKIAA=")}})
   ```
3. update its other field

   ```
   db.testData.update({_id: 10000}, {$set: {size: 20}})
   ```
4. check with oplog

   ```
   use local

   db.oplog.rs.find().sort({$natural: -1})
   ```

   you may see the following response:

   ```
   { "ts" : Timestamp(1435627154, 1), "h" : NumberLong("-4979206321598144076"), "v" : 2, "op" : "u", "ns" : "test.testData", "o2" : { "_id" : 10000 }, "o" : { "$set" : { "size" : 20 } } }
   { "ts" : Timestamp(1435627144, 1), "h" : NumberLong("2899524097634687825"), "v" : 2, "op" : "u", "ns" : "test.testData", "o2" : { "_id" : 10000 }, "o" : { "$set" : { "data" : BinData(0,"CgxVfs93PiT/DrxMSvASFgoNMTAuMTYwLjIyMi4xMhDEJxgKIAA=") } } }
   { "ts" : Timestamp(1435627136, 1), "h" : NumberLong("-8486373688715225152"), "v" : 2, "op" : "i", "ns" : "test.testData", "o" : { "_id" : 10000, "data" : BinData(0,""), "size" : 10 } }
   ```
5. dump these two oplog and replay it

   In bash shell:

   ```
   mongodump --port 27017 -d local -c oplog.rs --query '{"ts" : {$gte: Timestamp(1435627144, 1)}}' -o ./oplogD/

   mv ./oplogD/local/oplog.rs.bson ./oplogR/oplog.bson

   mongorestore --port 27017 --oplogReplay ./oplogR/
   ```

   **after this** you would find data not as expected. In my own, data changes to this.

   ```
   { "_id" : 10000, "data" : BinData(0,"ADRAAAAAPiT/DrxMSvASFgoNMTAuMTYwLjIyMi4xMhDEJxgKIAA="), "size" : 20 }
   ```

   The size field is really correct, but the data field is not correct.
6. The most **strange** thing would be this, if you dump only **one**  oplog and replay it, the data would be correct.

   ```
   mongodump --port 27017 -d local -c oplog.rs --query '{"ts" : Timestamp(1435627144, 1)}' -o ./tmpD/

   mv ./tmpD/local/oplog.rs.bson ./tmpR/oplog.bson

   mongorestore --port 27017 --oplogReplay ./tmpR/
   ```

   After oplog replayed, the 'data' field is quite correct.

   ```
   { "_id" : 10000, "data" : BinData(0,"CgxVfs93PiT/DrxMSvASFgoNMTAuMTYwLjIyMi4xMhDEJxgKIAA="), "size" : 10 }
   ```

   Why does this strange thing happen?

Comment: what version of mongod were you using at the time?  3.0 it seems, but which release, if you recall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was fixed in this commit.

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/commit/ed60bbfae7d2b5239bea69f162f0784e17995e91

Trace the bug report in JIRA.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-807